# Concatenating char to char*

Tags: c

I am trying to concatenate/append a char * and char. I am not a c expert so pardon me if this question doesn't make sense. I have tried multiple ways of doing it but nothing seems to work.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void assignMode()
{
      char modeString[] = "SPI_LOOP,SPI_CPOL";
      char *temp[]= (char *)malloc(strlen(modeString));
      int i,j;
      printf("Length of string a = %ld \n",strlen(modeString));
      for(i=0; i<= strlen(modeString); i++)
      {
        j =0;
        if(!(modeString[i] == ','))
        { 
          printf("Char: %c \n", modeString[i]);
          temp[j] = modeString[i];
          temp[j+1] = '\0';
          j++;
        }else
        {
          j = 0;
          printf("temp: %s\n", temp);
        }
      }
}

int main()
{
    assignMode();
}
```

modetest.c:36:19: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           temp[j] = modeString[i];

Comment: `temp` should either be `char* temp` or `char temp[]` (but with an actual size), but not `char* temp[]`

Comment: A conforming compiler should already stop at `char *temp[] = ...` since this declares an array of pointers of unknown size, but doesn't provide a valid constant expression initializer.

Comment: As a curious side-note, why do you have SPI register bit flags in string format to begin with?

Comment: lundin, The over all goal is to pass a string to assignMode() for example "SPI_LOOP,SPI_CPOL" which will be set in else block one after the other.

Comment: I changed char *temp[]= (char *)malloc(strlen(modeString)); `code` to char* temp[17]; `code`. assigning it a size but still running into the same issue

Comment: OT:  regarding: `for(i=0; i<= strlen(modeString); i++)`  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`  (I.E. unsigned long int) and the variable 'i' is an `int`,  This can be a problem and can be fixed by declaring `i` as in: `size_t i;`

Comment: regarding: `char *temp[]= (char *)malloc(strlen(modeString));`  This does not compile!.  Perhaps you meant: `char *temp = malloc(strlen(modeString));`  Notice, no `[]`.  Also, in C, the returned type from `malloc()` is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  The Cast just clutters the code.  correcting this statement will eliminate all the compiler messages except about trying to assign a `unsigned int` into a `int`

Comment: BTW, `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, so you should be using `%zd` to format it, not `%ld`.  Missing this suggests you haven't enabled a sensible level of warnings on your compiler.

Comment: @TobySpeight Good point! I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @user3629249 As for previous comment - I've edited my answer to address your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the mistake pointed out in the comments (removing `[]` from the declaration of `temp`), there are a couple of other 'errors' in your code, *if what your are trying to do is what I think*. (I'm assuming you want to print individual characters until you find a `,` delimiter, then print the extracted string at that point.)

First, you need to move your first `j = 0` statement to **outside** the `for` loop, so that it won't keep resetting each time (unless the comma is found). Second (assuming you want to print out the final 'extraction', even though there isn't a terminating comma, then you also need to check for the null terminator itself.

Here's a suggestion for what I ***think*** you're after (please feel free to correct my assumption):

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void assignMode()
{
    char modeString[] = "SPI_LOOP,SPI_CPOL";
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(strlen(modeString)); /// Note: temp should not be an ARRAY of pointers - just one!
    int i, j = 0; /// Initialise j here - NOT inside the for loop!
    printf("Length of string a = %zd \n", strlen(modeString)); /// Use "%zd" for size_t!
    for (i = 0; i <= (int)strlen(modeString); i++) /// Always safer to convert size_t to int before comparison!
    {
    //  j = 0; /// See comment above!
        if (!(modeString[i] == ',') && modeString[i]) /// This also takes the end-of-string as a token delimiter
        {
            printf("Char: %c \n", modeString[i]);
            temp[j] = modeString[i];
            temp[j + 1] = '\0';
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            j = 0;
            printf("temp: %s\n", temp);
        }
    }
    free(temp);/// Always FREE memory created with MALLOC when you're done with it!
}

int main()
{
    assignMode();
    return 0; /// Generally good practice to put this explicit return in main!
}
```

Output:

```
Length of string a = 17
Char : S
Char : P
Char : I
Char : _
Char : L
Char : O
Char : O
Char : P
temp : SPI_LOOP
Char : S
Char : P
Char : I
Char : _
Char : C
Char : P
Char : O
Char : L
temp : SPI_CPOL
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to concatenate/append a char * and char.

There are several options.

1. Assuming your string is changeable and the underlying array has enough space:

   ```
   char array[100] = "abracadabra";
   char suffix = '$';

   size_t alen = strlen(array);
   array[alen] = suffix;
   array[alen+1] = '\0';
   ```
2. Assuming your string is malloc'd and needs to grow:

   ```
   char *array = malloc(12);
   strcpy(array, "abracadabra");
   char suffix = '$';

   size_t alen = strlen(array);
   char *tmp = realloc(array, alen + 2); // space for suffix and '\0'
   if (tmp) { array = tmp; }
   else { fprintf(stderr, "No memory.\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

   array[alen] = suffix;
   array[alen+1] = '\0';

   // remember to free(array) later
   ```
3. Assuming the original string is read-only and needs to be copied somewhere

   ```
   char *text = "abracadabra":
   char suffix = '$';

   char *tmp = malloc(strlen(text) + 2); // add space for suffix and '\0'
   sprintf(tmp, "%s%c", text, suffix);

   // remember to free(tmp) later
   ```

Comment: I'd say that using the same storage as the target of `sprintf()` and as its input is dangerous at best.  I can't find where it's specifically disallowed, but I'm pretty sure it's not safe in general (i.e. when it's not the very first part of output).

Comment: thanks for the edit @TobySpeight; and also for the warning about my usage of `sprintf()`

Comment: @TonySpeight: removed dubious usage of `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEMS:

1. An array of char can be `char * temp = ...` or it can be `char temp [] = ...` but what you did (`char * temp []`) is an array of char array. For sure what you need is just a char array. The error `modetest.c: 36: 19: warning` occurred for this.
2. In your loop, `for(i=0; i<= max; i++)` you must use "i< max".
3. You should not call `strlen (modeString)` inside `for` condition. Instead, create a variable `int max = strlen (modeString);` and then the loop can be `for (i = 0; i <= max; i ++)`.   The way you have it now, `strlen` will called many times unnecessarily.
4. You can reduce all `modeString [i]` to a single call `char c = modeString [i];` and then use `c` wherever you need it.
5. You should finish the routine with `printf("temp: %s\n", temp)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void assignMode() {
    char modeString[] = "SPI_LOOP,SPI_CPOL";
    size_t max = strlen(modeString);
    char * temp = malloc(max + 2);
    int j = 0;
    printf("Length of string a = %zd\n", max);
    for (int i=0; i< max; i++) {
        char c = modeString[i];
        if(!(c == ',')) {
            printf("Char: %c \n", c);
            temp[j] = c;
            temp[j+1] = '\0';
            j++;
        } else {
            j = 0;
            printf("temp: %s\n", temp);
        }
    }
    printf("temp: %s\n", temp);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    assignMode();
    return 0; }
```

Comment: Actually, using `i < max` rather than `i <= max` will prevent dealing with the terminating `nul` as a 'token delimiter' (as my answer does).